# Spotify App redirects to wrong browser on iOS after authentication - bug

Tags: spotify

During a browser based authentication (oauth) some iOS users experience the flow as their Spotify app opening to authenticate rather than in the browser.

When this happens the redirection back to the site uses the default browser rather than the browser that started the flow.

So for example a user may start to authenticate in Chrome or in the Facebook Browser, but is then redirected after authentication to Safari.

If you are maintaining session or states to check against CSRF then this will breaks that.

I also think it would be more consistent for the user to send them back to their original browser.

Comment: I have exactly this issue with my webapp on an iPhone 8. Do you know of any way to fix this? I haven not found a way to tackle this for my users....